# Как создать фильтр для товаров с одним или больше значениями

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, запрос, phpquery

Есть сайт [Elessi](http://elessi.nasatheme.com/product-category/fashions/?sidebar=left-classic), если кто-то знает подскажите, как сделать такой фильтр товаром. Структуру сайта я написал. Только БД и функцию вывода не знаю как правильно сделать. Если у кого-то предложения? Мне подойдет если вы просто скинете ссылку на какой-то исходник. Потому что уже 6 день голову ломаю. Не знаю что придумать... Если у товара один цвет или размер, тут все понятно. Но если в один товар, но у него три цвета я уже не знаю что делать. Заранее спасибо!

PS: Все что я хочу знать: Как устроить БД с фильтрами и как создавать SQL запрос

Answer (score 0):

> Как устроить БД с фильтрами

Как и любую другую бд. Разбиваете объект на атрибуты и сохраняете в соответствующих таблицах. Все "фильтры" делаются запросами. Если доступно несколько значений - создаете отдельную таблицу и джоините её по мере необходимости

> Как создавать SQL запрос.

В вашем случае это может быть что-то вроде SELECT * FROM goods WHERE color IN ("Red", "Blud", "White") AND price < 500. Думаю, как пример, для понимания принципа построения таких запросов подойдет. Более конкретно сложно сказать. Я не видел, что у вас в бд творится.

На всякий случай уточню, что объект с информацией о всех ваших фильтрах должен спускаться на ДАО уровень и уже там парсится. Не надо генерировать сотни методов под каждую коомбинацию